# How can you adjust manually when the collapse-able burger button appeared with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this set of codes, taken from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar.

```
<button aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed navbar-toggle" data-target="#main_menu" data-toggle="collapse">
<span class="sr-only">toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

It is just a basic burger button for mobile or small view, nothing fancy. The Bootstrap 3 handle this manually when the horizontal viewport getting smaller at some rate the burger button appeared.

My question is that how can I manually show the burger button (instead of it magically shown through Bootstrap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define an Id for the button... and show/hide it from codebehind when your conditions are met

```
 buttonId.Visible = True/False
```

Comment: Thanks! And also removing the Bootstrap class `class="collapsed navbar-toggle"` so that the button will not automatically shown off/on.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hidden by CSS if the screensize exceeds a certain width (768px).

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
```

If you want to always show it, remove this rule or overwrite it with your own rule.